# Odd tag roundup 12/7/11

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I don't know that all of these need to die, perhaps some are deserving.  They just all seemed a little weird.

[gemcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemcraft) - We have tags for most of the games, maybe this should just die?

[music](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [soundtrack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack) - looking at them, maybe they should be synonyms?

[races](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/races) - sort of ambiguously used and not very descriptive.

[sneak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sneak) - probably belongs with [sneaking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sneaking) as a synonym for [stealth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth)

These are more just "what's the purpose of filtering questions this way?" kind of tags:

[options](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/options)

[item-drops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/item-drops)

I pretty much expect these to live, given the current tag climate.  They just don't seem terribly useful to me personally.

Comment: Gemcraft means the original flash game: "gemcraft", I'm pretty sure. I'll go fix Sneak right now.

Comment: OK.  I'll handle the mis-tagged q's under gemcraft then.

Comment: I eliminated races.

Answer (score 2):

I think [gemcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemcraft) should be a synonym or something of [gemcraft-the-forgotten](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemcraft-the-forgotten) or something similar, as the full title of the original game was: **Gemcraft: Chapter 1: The Forgotten**

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, the remaining non-synonym tags are now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]